# explanation of RHEL/CentOS 7 yum repo gpg key

Tags: yum, repository, gpg

I do not understand how **one** gpg key can work for any of a thousand rpm's downloaded from a repository?  For example, in RHEL/Centos 7.x

- install EPEL (extra packages for enterprise linux); results in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` containing `gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7`
- ok so that's **one** gpg key, in a file, how does this work for any rpm then downloaded from the EPEL repository?
- I thought the *key* was contained in the .rpm header, and that key is generated based on the contents of that rpm.  But all rpm's are different so shouldn't there be a different *key* in each rpm?  How does one `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7` apply to anything downloaded from the EPEL repo website?

Comment: is it because each individual rpm MD5 checksum is based on that **one** GPG key contained somewhere in the header(s) which is separate from the guts {*archive* section} of the rpm?  And the GPG key is up in the header and can be extracted or replaced outright whenever one wants, but if it changes then the existing MD5 checksum is no longer valid?  And because the gpg key and MD5 checksum are up in the header(s) those can be replaced at will?

Answer (score 2):

RPM and repository signature verification is based on GPG’s asymmetric cryptography, using a key pair. `RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7` is the public part of the key; there’s also a private part, which is a closely-guarded secret. RPMs pushed to the EPEL repositories, and the repository metadata itself, are signed using the private part of the key. `yum` (and `dnf`) can verify the signature using the public part of the key.

RPMs store their own signature, not the key used to sign them.

The idea behind the separation is that it allows out-of-band verification. If RPMs carried their signature and the key used to verify it, anyone with access to the repository could push an RPM there and `yum` would accept it. Since the key is stored locally, `yum` can verify that the signature was made by someone with access to the private key, which provides a stronger guarantee than the package’s presence in a given repository. The configuration of a repository in your local system says “retrieve packages from this base URL, and additionally, verify that they are signed by this key” (in the `.repo` file, `gpgcheck` forces package signature verification if it’s enabled, and `repo_gpgcheck` forces repository metadata verification if it’s enabled).